# Backup software for Windows supporting near-realtime directly to the cloud

Tags: windows, backup, cloud

I am looking for backup software, for which I am very happy to pay for, but only if it meets the following constraints:

- Must run on Windows
- Must be near-real-time. Ideally real-time.
- Must able to backup directly to the cloud, not through a service. I
  have a lot of Azure Credits and I would like to use them, but given
  the low S3 cost that's okay too

I am currently running CloudBerry, but that's rather flaky software when it comes to larger sets of data being shuffled around. I just don't trust it.

I looked at Acronis (for 'normal' users), which would've been great as you can map an Azure FileStore on Windows, if it wasn't for the case that my provider blocks that port, and I don't want to set up a permanent VPN on all of my machines for that.

Worst comes to worst I buy a Synology, but 4TB in, and let my machines backup there, and let the Synology backup to Azure/S3...

In the past I have used CrashPlan, but since they killed their home plan I have been wandering around looking for alternatives. To this day my search remains fruitless.

Comment: Are you interested in large image-type backups or in just having a single, constantly updated backup?

Comment: @IronEagle realtime continuous backup!

Comment: It depends by what are you syncing. Pictures, PDFs and other small files or very large files? Why don't you use GoogleDrive or Dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

Syncthing ([syncthing.net](https://syncthing.net)) might meet your needs.  Runs on Windows, but also on Linux & Mac.  Open-source, encrypted file transfers, real-time syncing, optional file versioning.  You should be able to install it on a cloud server and have it just sync to whatever you want on your local machine.  No static ip requirement - it figures out routing by itself.  It's also pretty great at that - I'm on a fairly restrictive University network and it has no problems. It's also free, and has the benefit that if you want to sync to another computer, or an on-site backup, it's a few clicks to sync with that computer as well.